# Prove that $f(x)y+g(x)$ does not factor as a product of two polynomials of positive degree.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be polynomials  that have no common factor of positive degree. Prove that $f(x)y+g(x)$ does not factor as a product of two polynomials of positive degree.

I am now learning intersection multiplicity at the origin of two polynomials. I don't know how to prove this using this part of knowledge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have polynomials over a field: if $f(x) y + g(x)$ were to factor into two polynomials, there must not be any $y^2$ terms, so it must factor as $(a(x) y + b(x)) c(x)$. Then it follows that $a(x) c(x) = f(x)$ and $b(x) c(x) = g(x)$. So $c(x)$ has degree $0$.

Thus if $f(x) y + g(x)$ factors into two polynomials, one of them has degree $0$.

Comment: How to prove it using the intersection multiplicity ?

Comment: @Nicholas I'm sorry, i don't know. I just saw that there was an elementary argument, and gave it.